# How do I Programatically add a Web Site (C#) to IIS 6.0?

Tags: c#, iis, web, installation

We have a web application that until now installed under the "Default Web Site" in IIS. A customer now wants us to install it under a different web site, and we want to do that from the installer.
My question is in 2 parts: A) How do I programatically add another web site alongside the 'default web site'?
B) We are using Windows Installer - is there a way to trigger whatever code I write for section A from within the installer in time for the installation to take place at the new location? It looks like overriding Install() is too late in the game...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we use a js windows script to update our virtual directories between branches, I would imagine that you could use the same objects to create a website

```
var iisPath = "IIS://localhost/W3SVC/" + siteID;
var site = GetObject(iisPath);
```

Microsoft has a [fairly extensive article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2db9f530-2a10-40bd-b68d-667ba62ac5fe.mspx?mfr=true) on configuring IIS 6 programatically.  As long as your MSI can call a batch file, this article should help out.

[This article](http://www.winscripter.com/WSH/ADSI/272.aspx) also has a complete script file that creates a website.

Comment: I guess I assumed that the website was C# not the requested Program.  However, there is no reason these objects can't be used in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some C# code for programmatically creating a site:

```
1    using System.DirectoryServices;
 2    using System;
 3    
 4    public class IISAdmin
 5    {
 6       public static int CreateWebsite(string webserver, string serverComment, string serverBindings, string homeDirectory)
 7       {
 8          DirectoryEntry w3svc = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/w3svc");
 9          
 10         //Create a website object array
 11         object[] newsite = new object[]{serverComment, new object[]{serverBindings}, homeDirectory};
 12         
 13         //invoke IIsWebService.CreateNewSite
 14         object websiteId = (object)w3svc.Invoke("CreateNewSite", newsite);
 15         
 16         return (int)websiteId;
 17      
 18      }
 19   
 20      public static void Main(string[] args)
 21      {
 22         int a = CreateWebsite("localhost", "Testing.com", ":80:Testing.com", "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot");
 23         Console.WriteLine("Created website with ID: " + a);
 24      }
 25      
 26   }
```

reference: http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/cs_create_website_iis6.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WiX to create your MSI, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624918/using-wix-to-create-an-iis-virtual-directory).

Comment: Nope, no WiX here, just basic Windows Installer (oh, the joy... not.)

Answer (score 0):

Not really an expert at MSI files, but you can add a website through scripting using adsutil.vbs. Poor man's way to handle this is to have your installer drop the files at a location without creating a website then run a later step with the script to create a website with the root at this location. Bonus points for making this optional for nudgy IIS admins like myself who hate installers touching IIS at all.