# Convert folder under virtual directory to Application, using WIX

Tags: iis, wix

How can I convert a directory under a virtual directory to an application, using WIX?

WIX installs the following Virtual Directory to IIS, and I wish it to also convert the *webservice* folder to an application.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could not find a way to do this through WIX or the IIS extension, so I resorted to calling an external command. For future reference, the commands are:

**IIS 5**

```
C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\mkwebdir.vbs -c Localhost -w "Default Web Site" -v "sentry/webservice","{physical path}"
C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs appcreateinproc w3svc/1/root/sentry/webservice
```

**IIS 6**

```
C:\Windows\System32\iisvdir.vbs /create "Default Web Site/Sentry/webservice" webservice "{physical path}"
```

**IIS 7**

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd add app /site.name:"Default Web Site" /path:/Sentry/webservice /physicalPath:"{physical path}"
```

Comment: Can you post the source of this information? Especially for IIS6. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the [IISExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_webvirtualdir.htm), as Daniel Morritt suggests. As it's very difficult to find sample code for this I thought I'd post how I did it.

```
<!-- Your example uses the default web site. -->
<iis:WebSite Id="DefaultWebSite" Description="Default Web Site" SiteId="*">
  <iis:WebAddress Id="DefaultWebAddress" Port="80"/>
</iis:WebSite>

<!-- Web Dir Properties to enable access to a Web Application. -->
<iis:WebDirProperties Id="AnonymousExecuteAndScript" 
                      Read="yes" 
                      Write="no" 
                      Execute="yes" 
                      Script="yes" 
                      AnonymousAccess="yes" 
                      Index="no" 
                      LogVisits="no"/>

<!-- Assumes the presence of this directory reference. -->
<DirectoryRef Id="SentryWebServiceDir">
  <Component Id="SentryWebServiceComponent" Guid="{GUID-GOES-HERE}">

    <iis:WebVirtualDir Id="SentryWebService"
                       DirProperties="AnonymousExecuteAndScript" 
                       Alias="Sentry/webservice"
                       Directory="SentryWebServiceDir"
                       WebSite="DefaultWebSite">

      <!-- Make this virtual directory a web application -->
      <iis:WebApplication Id="SentryWebServiceApp" Name="webservice" WebAppPool="DefaultAppPool"/>
    </iis:WebVirtualDir>

    <!-- Workaround for the need for a KeyPath for this component. -->
    <RegistryValue Root="HKLM"
              Key="SOFTWARE\YourCompany\Sentry\WebService"
              KeyPath="yes"
              Value="1"
              Type="binary"
              Name="Installed"
              Id="SentryWebServiceInstalled"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

All of the above can be nested in a `<Fragment>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference to the WiX [IISExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_webvirtualdir.htm) to your project and create one using this.

A good example of this can be found here: [Using WiX to create an IIS virtual directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624918/using-wix-to-create-an-iis-virtual-directory)

Comment: That is the way the existing Sentry Virtual Directory is created, and does not work for creating an application under an existing virtual directory (note the 'Website' property of iis:WebVirtualDir)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this approach, and it works:

http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg04374.html

It says to put the whole path in the Alias, for example

```
<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="VIRTDIR_Sentry_webservice"
                       Directory="WebService"
                       Alias="Sentry/webservice"
                       WebSite="SITE_Default"> ...
```